# Split dataframe on multiple columns and values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through a dataframe to create multiple dataframes (unknown number) based on multiple columns using groupby:

```
    df_sliced = {}
for product, value in df['Product'].unique() and df['Value'].unique():
    df_sliced[product, value] = df.groupby(['Product','Value'])
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
df_sliced = {prod_val: group for prod_val, group in df.groupby(['Product','Value'])}
```